# Can I profile a binary for a different architecture?

Tags: profiling, emulation, qemu, profiler

Pretty much the title question. I just need to know how many times each instruction gets executed. I have an ARMv7 binary (a bare metal one actually), so I tried using QEMU, but I got non constant results:

- attaching GDB to `qemu-system-arm -s -S` works as expected and allows me to recover the trace of execution, but it is slow
- using `qemu-system-arm -d cpu` apparently gets initialized in a different way, takes different paths on a conditional branch, and in the end doesn't execute the pieces of code I want

Is there a tool I can use to get a profile/execution trace for a different architecture? Correct me if I'm wrong, but Valgrind and `perf` cannot work in this setting.

Thanks!